# Here REST API return special characters like "ß", even when the language=en parameter is set

Tags: here-api

I'm using Here REST API to geocode international addresses, and I'm working on some Germany addresses with a lot of `Straße` in the spreadsheet.

For example, address like `Löderburger Straße 14, 39418 Staßfurt, Deutschland`, what I expected is getting `Loderburger Strasse 14, 39418 Stassfurt, Germany` from the API return. But, the result from Here is `Löderburger Straße 14, 39418 Staßfurt, Germany`. The country name is converted into english, however, I still get `ß` when I add the `language=en` parameter when calling the API. Is there any other ways to get the results in english?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve? I assume you have geo-positions and use reverse geocoding to get an address for them. The address you get is usually the one used locally, unless it's a non-latin script where you may get a transcription, or there is a translation available, which can be the case for country names and bigger cities, but rarely for street names (except in multi-lingual areas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HERE Map data, the address is coded in local language by default. If the local language is non-latin then there would be a transcription coded. In multi-lingual areas explicit translation are coded for street names as well depending on the languages used in the region. The English translation would be coded for Country / Bigger city names globally but rarely for street names.